# Removing ampersand from URL in Codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination

In my Codeigniter project, I am trying to implement Pagination using CI's Pagination library. My Controller function is as shown below :

```
function uploadhistory()
{
    $data['num']=20;
    $this->load->library('pagination'); // library for pagination
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'video/uploadhistory/'; 
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['num']; 
    $config['per_page'] = 3; 
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['page']='video/uploadhistory';
    $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
}
```

The problem is, pagination URL is coming like:

http://www.domain.com/project/video/uploadhistory/&per_page=3.

**What I need is like:**

> http://www.domain.com/project/video/uploadhistory/3.

I have set `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` in *application/config/config.php* file.

Can anyone help me to find a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried setting it to `false`?, then `uploadhistory($page_num = 1)`

Comment: Dude when you use link like http://www.domain.com/project/video/uploadhistory/3 then it means you are passing param to controller function like `function uploadhistory($id)` then it will work as you wanted

Comment: `$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;` try this after above chnages

Comment: no any changes still. Now also the link contains & and is giving me page not found error.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this

```
$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

The main problem here is that the default value of "uri_segment" is 3, which represents the 'uploadhistory" in your URL. You have to force it to 4, so that it takes the correct segment of the URL.

More info on the [Codeigniter Pagination Class doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)